# Why is my API data not showing up on my django html page?

Tags: node.js, django, api

I am fairly new to coding in general so apologies for my dumb question.

I created an API in Node. I put some filler data in the DB and tested the API. Works fine.

I created a Django app that attempts to access the data in the API. I am using a CORS module so I can access the API on my local machine.

When I load the home page, a GET request is sent to the API, and I can see that the API receives the request. I don't know if any data is being sent back.

Nothing shows up in the table on the home page.

-API routes- (all routes are starting with /questions)

```
router.get('/', queryQuestions);
router.post('/', addQuestion);
router.delete('/:uid', deleteQuestion);
router.get('/:uid', queryQuestion);
router.patch('/:uid', updateQuestion);
```

-Django view-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib import messages

def home(request):
    import json
    import requests
    api_request = requests.get("http://localhost:3000/questions")
    try:
        api = json.loads(api_request.content)
    except Exception as e:
        api = "Error..."
    return render(request, 'frontend/home.html', {'api': api})
```

-Django template 'home' (sample)-

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Question</th>
            <th scope="col">Category</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% if api %}
            {% for list_item in api %}
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{ list_item.uid }}</td>
                    <td>{{ list_item.content }}</td>
                    <td>{{ list_item.category }}</td>
                  </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

-urls-

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
]
```

Comment: Add your url.py file it will be more clear.

Comment: added urls... realizing that may be where I messed up.... What did I miss?

Comment: I am still lost.

Comment: print(api) print the API  response.

Comment: My instructor helped me with this issue. I am having a new issue with the POST method. The updated code and my new issue can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64729657/how-do-i-use-a-post-method-to-communicate-with-an-external-api-in-django