# How do I use a POST method to communicate with an external API in Django?

Tags: django, api, post

I received help from my instructor to figure out the GET command. I am struggling with the POST command.

-View-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib import messages
import json
import requests
from ast import literal_eval
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

def add_question(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        url = 'http://localhost:3000/questions/'
        payload = {'content':request.POST.get("content"), 'category':request.POST.get("category")}
        res = requests.post(url, data = (payload))
        print(res)
    return Response(res.json())
```

Part of my problem is that most of the previously published advice on this topic is over 3 years old. I don't think the 'rest_framework' module is used much for this purpose anymore. It's hard to tell.

Right now the error I am getting is: "raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) "POST /add_question HTTP/1.1" 500 92794"

The GET method that worked for me was this:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print('home')
    api_request = requests.get("http://localhost:3000/questions/")#.json()
    try:
        print( 'api_request='+str(api_request))
        q = literal_eval(api_request.content.decode('utf8'))
        print('q=', q, type(q))
        print( q['data'])
        json_obj = json.dumps(q['data'])
        print('json_obj=', json_obj, type(json_obj))
       
        #api = json.loads(api_request.content)
        api = json.loads(json_obj)
    except Exception as e:
        print( 'Exception e='+str(e))
        api = "Error..."
    else: 
        if request.method == 'POST':
            post_request = requests.post("http://localhost:3000/questions/")
            print(post_request)
    return render(request, 'frontend/home.html', {'api': api})
```

The API I am using is one I created in Node.js. The error I am getting from Node when I attempt the post is: "ReferenceError: question is not defined
at addQuestion (file:///C:/nodepract/Project05/api/routes/questions.js:60:47)"

I changed the view to the following.

```
def add_question(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        url = 'http://localhost:3000/questions/'
        data = json.dumps(request.POST)
        res = requests.post(url, data)
        print("res.text = " + res.text)
        return Response(res.json())
```

Currently getting following error.
"ReferenceError: question is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown because the data that you receive from the external API `http://localhost:3000/questions/` is not JSON data.

To debug the response, print the res.text before res.json call.

Comment: This is what res.text says: "ReferenceError: question is not defined"   
I also updated my original post.

Comment: Mind posting the stack trace?

Comment: You have an issue with the server providing the http://localhost:3000/questions/ endpoint. Debug that, not this!